# Performance of ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

From an experiment I got a huge 3d data set (~ 4*10^6 data points) which I display with `ListPointPlot3D`.

How can I improve the speed of showing the plot in the notebook or saving it with `Export`.

Here is my example code:

```
SeedRandom[1];

data = RandomReal[10, {4000000, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.0923029, Null}

plot3d = ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Tiny, Boxed -> True, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
  ViewPoint -> {2, -2.4, 2}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

{56.4218, Null}

Export[FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "plot3d.bmp"}, plot3d, "BMP"]; // AbsoluteTiming

{1255.23, Null}

Export[FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "plot3d.png"}, plot3d, "PNG"]; // AbsoluteTiming

{2126.69, Null}
```

Comment: do you really need all the points? If you do like `ListPointPlot3D[RandomSample[data, 10000]]` you will often get what you need and much faster.

Comment: @george2079: Yes I need to see all the points, at least the projection which the 3d plot gives. The whole point distribution can be very different from the view of a subset of only 10000 points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Graphics3D` using `Point` with `VertexColors` is much faster for producing the graphics:

```
 data = RandomReal[10, {4000000, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(g3d = Graphics3D[{PointSize[Tiny], 
      Point[data, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, 1]]])]}, 
     Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
     ViewPoint -> {2, -2.4, 2}, 
     AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]; ) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.131143

```
 g3d
```

[image]

With a smaller dataset with `400,000` points `ListPointPlot3D` takes `7.025276` seconds.

Also, using the `File >> Save Selection As` route is much faster than using `Export`.

Comment: This is impressing: why is `Graphics` so much faster then `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: @mrz, I guess it is because it  avoids overhead that `*Plot` and `*Chart`  routines have to incur before they  eventually invoke `Graphics`.

Comment: For `File >> Save Selection As` it is necessary to display the graphics in the notebook, which takes time. When I only want to save the plot there is probably no other command than `Export?`